# Let's get critical: Jun 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Hinduism Stack Exchange](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the Navavidha Bhakti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-is-the-navavidha-bhakti)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Did Valmiki - Ramayana author, write about Lord Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/did-valmiki-ramayana-author-write-about-lord-krishna)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Did the divine architect Vishwakarma cause the Earth to submerge?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7395/did-the-divine-architect-vishwakarma-cause-the-earth-to-submerge)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Who was the father of Vali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/who-was-the-father-of-vali)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is there a time, place or method for chanting the holy name?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/is-there-time-place-or-method-of-chanting-holy-name)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to feel pain or happiness of other beings in true form?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7177/how-to-feel-pain-or-happiness-of-other-beings-in-true-form)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why is it not recommended to turn back immediately after praying in a temple?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/is-this-true-regarding-a-temple-visit)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Why do hindus need to worship more gods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/why-do-hindus-need-to-worship-more-gods)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [What are the cultural and religious differences between Hindus in India and Bali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7173/what-is-the-cultural-and-religious-difference-between-bali-and-indian-hindus)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [When did lord Hanuman fight with Ravana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7391/when-did-lord-hanuman-fought-with-ravana)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 6)

---